# generating the HMAC different java C # to the same inputs

Tags: java, c#, hash, md5, hmac

**Java function**

```
 private static byte[] getHmac(String login, String password, byte[] key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    // byte[] Login = login.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);//OK
    byte[] pwdBytes = (login + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);//OK

    //MD5
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    md.update(pwdBytes);
    byte[] pwdbytes_md5 = md.digest();//OK

    //HMAC
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
    SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(key, mac.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(sk);
    mac.update(pwdbytes_md5);

    return mac.doFinal();
}
```

**C# Function**

```
public byte[] GetHash(string login, string password, byte[] key)
    {

        byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(login + password);


        MD5 md = MD5.Create();
        byte[] pwdbytes_md5 = md.ComputeHash(pwdBytes);
        Hash = new HMACMD5(pwdbytes_md5).ComputeHash(key);

        return Hash;
    }
```

Inputs:

login =    happy
password = 89631139
key = [0x04,0x00,0x00,0x50,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x6b,0x2e,0x8e,0x6b,0x3c,0xb7,0x02,0x06]

outputs (var value in debug) c#

key      = 0x04,0x00,0x00,0x50,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x6b,0x2e,0x8e,0x6b,0x3c,0xb7,0x02,0x06 = ok
md5  = 0x5a,0x6a,0x0b,0xef,0xff,0x83,0x2f,0x61,0x5e,0x16,0xc7,0x3d,0x5a,0x6e,0xde,0x65 = ok
Login    = 0x68,0x61,0x70,0x70,0x79 = ok
pwdBytes = 0x68,0x61,0x70,0x70,0x79,0x38,0x39,0x36,0x33,0x31,0x31,0x33,0x39 = ok
Hash     = 0x6a,0xcd,0xad,0x49,0x8d,0x54,0xfe,0xf1,0xca,0x4e,0x74,0xd8,0x52,0x46,0x09,0x6a = ok

these are the expected outputs for the variables as well as the return of the function,
but in the function written in java all the outputs are, except the return of the function that in the case is the hash, that of C # is correct, but I can not in any way return the same value in java.

in java always returns this value> A3 DE F0 6C 9D 53 87 4A 18 23 FD 2C F6 E4 15 0D
However the desired value for the return of the function must be what is returned by the function in C #

Does anyone know a correct way to implement the function of c # in java, I have already searched and everything that was website and had no solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the C# code. The key and the data are switched. If you do the same in Java you get the same result as in C#:

```
    private static byte[] getHmac(final String data, final byte[] key)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    // byte[] Login = login.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);//OK
    final byte[] pwdBytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);// OK

    // MD5
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    md.update(pwdBytes);
    final byte[] pwdbytes_md5 = md.digest();// OK

    // HMAC
    final Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
    final SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(pwdbytes_md5, mac.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(sk);
    mac.update(key);

    return mac.doFinal();
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much.

This function was a headache.